# I can't paste Twig code in a JSON script tag in PhpStorm

Tags: json, twig, phpstorm

I'm trying to put some Twig code in a JSON tag in my page (technically `ld+json` but the results are the same), and here's what I'm encountering:

When I try to paste/move twig code, it doesn't show.
When I write my code, it disappears on format and save.

The problem does not occur on a `.html` file with the same render.
The problem only occurs on `.html.twig` file extensions.

I'm guessing there is kind a JSON validation for Twig elements, but how can I disable it ?

My example code :

```
{% set foo = 'bar' %}

<script type="application/json">

</script>
```

If I disable the Twig support in the plugins, the problem disappears (but I lose twig support which I don't want), so I'm sure it comes from this plugin.

Comment: Just wondering if these YouTrack threads are related:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38976, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-37733 (less)

Comment: Yes, this is the same bug, thanks !